# Find all users at a certain stage in the process

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `Patient` which follows a process defined with multiple `Phase`s. When a patient is at a phase, there is a `Status` created, connecting patient and phase at a specific time stamp.

In MySQL my tables look like:

```
patient:
  id (int)

phase:
  id     (int)
  order: (int)
  name:  (varchar)

status:
  patient_id: (int, FK)
  phase_id:   (int, FK)
  timestamp:  (datetime)
```

Now I have phases A > B > C > D. I want to select all patients who are **now** at phase B or C. Patients only at phase A must be excluded, patients at phase D (so having a status for B and C) must be excluded too.

**My trials**

So I want a select something like this to start with:

```
SELECT p.*, s.*, ph.*
FROM patient p
LEFT JOIN status s on p.id  = s.patient_id
LEFT JOIN phase ph on ph.id = s.phase_id
WHERE s.id IN 
(
  // sub query
)
ORDER BY s.timestamp
```

I thought to select all patients with a given status x. The status x is something like this to start with:

```
SELECT status.*, phase.name
FROM status
LEFT JOIN phase ON phase.id=status.phase_id
WHERE phase.name IN ('B', 'C')
GROUP BY status.patient_id
```

But I cannot solve the rest: obviously there is no exclusion made for people further in the process. If I add a `max(status.timestamp) as max_timestamp` in the select, I see the `status.timestamp` and `max_timestamp` differ.

In this query I haven't even used the `order` in the phase table, I simply wanted to order on `id` first, but since the process might change over time, I thought that would be a bad idea. So that's missing as well.

**Question**

Perhaps I am completely on the wrong track and I do not need the subquery at all. I think the problem is quite clear: how can I select the patients based on a list of given phases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Added join to status table to show timestamp of last status change.

The query below gives the current status of all patients.  The `phase.phase_order` field must be unique, but that seems right.  I think what you are saying in your question is actually that `phase.id` gives the phase ordering as well, in which case, `phase.order` is not needed and can be replaced with `phase.id`.

```
select
    p.id as patient_id,
    p.name as patient_name,
    ph.name as phase_name,
    s.timestamp as timestamp
from (
    select p.id as patient_id, max(ph.phase_order) as phase_order
    from patient p
    join status s on s.patient_id = p.id
    join phase ph on ph.id = s.phase_id
    group by p.id, p.name
) current
join patient p on p.id = current.patient_id
join phase ph on ph.phase_order = current.phase_order
join status s on s.patient_id = p.id and s.phase_id = ph.id
;
```

To only show patients in a given phase, add `where ph.name = 'phasename'` to the above query.

Comment: Awesome! I have no idea what you did with the magic `from () <name>` syntax, but this worked. If I could give you +2 I'd have done that :)

Comment: A small addition, would it be possible to extract the last status as well? Then I can populate a list based on the timestamp from the last event.

Comment: @JurianSluiman I've added the status timestamp as requested.  Enjoy!  The "from (...) <name>" clause defines a subquery that we can then join on.  Imagine it's creating a new table with the results of the select statement inside the parentheses and we can refer to the new table using <name>

Answer (score 0):

#### Use this query:

```
SELECT p.*, s.*, ph.*
    FROM patient p
    LEFT JOIN status s on p.id  = s.patient_id
    LEFT JOIN phase ph on ph.id = s.phase_id
    WHERE p.id IN 
    (
       -- Those phase IDs you want.
    )
    ORDER BY s.timestamp
```

Comment: Still I don't get your problem. What's the flow anyway?

Comment: I implemented an event log. I want to check the last event occurred for a given entity. Above answer explains the case in SQL pretty well.